# Попытка получить элемент массива - ошибка "pointer to a function used in arithmetic"

Tags: c++

Есть класс Pet:

```
Class Pet
{
public:
int id;
Pet* operator[](int i) const
{
  return pt[i];
}
Pet** pt;
int arrlength;
}
```

Есть конструкторы копирования и перемещения (стандартно определены):

```
Pet::Pet(const Pet& copied) const;
Pet::Pet(Pet&& tmp);
```

Такой код:

```
Pet aaa;
aaa.id = 1;
aaa.pt = new Pet*[10];
aaa.arrlength = 10;
aaa.pt[0] = new Pet;
aaa.pt[0]->id = 777;
Pet bbb(Pet(aaa));
Pet* ppp = bbb[0];//здесь ошибка
```

Выдает ошибку "pointer to a function used in arithmetic", подчеркивая закрывающую квадратную скобку. Но ведь bbb - не имя функции?

Answer (score 0):

Забавно - как вам удалось создать константный конструктор? :)

```
Pet::Pet(const Pet& copied) const;
```

А не срабатывает - потому что считает, что вы объявили функцию `bbb`, принимающую `Pet`, и возвращающую `Pet`.

```
Pet bbb{Pet(aaa)};
```

или

```
Pet bbb = Pet(aaa);
```

помогут.

P.S. Та же ошибка, что и объявление (якобы) переменной типа `type` в выражении

```
type name();
```

Вот, взгляните на такой код - тут у вас вопросов нет?

```
int f(int (x))
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{
    cout << f(1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Да, последний const в конструкторе напечатан по невнимательности.